# Save multiple objects in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have a common class `GameObject` and several of its child classes. Each of them has its own additional variables. When saving a game, I need to save all objects of these classes.

I had the idea to save information about each object in JSON and then save these JSONs to an array inside the `SaveGame` object, but Unreal Engine does not provide an opportunity to work with JSON. I also had a thought to serialize these objects, but the Unreal Engine does not do this either.

What should I do?

**Unreal Engine 4.18.3 Blueprint**

Comment: Maybe someone at least knows how to convert a `struct` to `string`?

Comment: Since my answer would be really long, I just leave this link for you: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Save_System,_Read_%26_Write_Any_Data_to_Compressed_Binary_Files You can create `SaveGameState` class with all wanted data, then propagate values to this class (ideally by having Blueprint Interface to Save/Load data between your blueprint and `SaveGameState`) and then just call your C++ implementation to save/load data to HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only blueprints you can't write JSON or handle files, and that's the big limit of blueprints. You may find some plugin in the marketplace that writes JSON files with blueprints (like [this](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/json-blueprint)) but I suggest you to start coding in c++ because it's very difficult to handle dictionaries in blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you want to use JSON but Unreal Engine generally uses a DataAsset object type , there are some plugins but in general you could

1. create your own parser and generate USTRUCTs on compilation time.
2. However if you are using JSON to pass server information a parser is needed to a struct.
3. On the other hand , you could in theory use UnrealJS to pass the JSON as a JS object instead of using BPS

Answer (score 0):

The [VaRest](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/varest-plugin) plugin lets you read JSON from a URL or from a local file. Not sure about the local one since I'm using a custom file reader implemented with [FFileHelper](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FFileHelper/LoadFileToString/2/).

If you're going that far, my suggestion is to not use the `SaveGame` object at all. Just create it locally and read it whenever necessary. It gives you more control, in my opinion.